# How to PCA reduction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pca

I am new to Matlab and have some problems using built in packages for PCA reduction. I have 37 objects each represented by 161 dimensional vector, that means i have 161 x 37 matrix called P. I need to reduce vector dimension to 3. so that each object will be represented by 3 dimensional vector. I have tried something with princomp(P) but i don't know which output to take.

[COEFF,SCORE] = princomp(P); 
newData=SCORE(:,1:3);

I think newData are not the right vectors ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to transpose your data because `princomp` expects observations on rows:

```
[COEFF,SCORE] = princomp(P.');
newData=SCORE(1:3.:).';
```

Alternatively you can use `pca` function to give you only the first 3 principal components:

```
[COEFF,SCORE] = pca(P.', 'NumComponents', 3)
newData=SCORE.';
```

Comment: this is the simplest way to perform dimensionality reduction with PCA.  +1